# how can i run another process in heroku

Tags: python-3.x, popen

I have two files in Heroku like "app.py" and "notify.py". 
when I run the "app.py". 
In some case, I'd like to run "notify.py", so I use this function "subprocess.Popen" to call "notify.py" .and I hope that process "notify.py" can run in loop, even after the main process ends. 
How can I do that?

By the way, I get the error like this

> /bin/sh: 1: ./notify.py: Permission denied

I use some methods like below

1. `child = subprocess.Popen(['./notify.py'], shell=True, cwd='/app', stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`
2. `child = subprocess.call(['./notify.py'], shell=True, cwd='/app', stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

but all doesn't work

and I try another like this
i make a function `notify()` in app.py
and change the code like below

`child = subprocess.Popen([notify(text)], shell=True)`

it work.
But it will run "notify(text)" then print "test" and return.
Please tell me why and how can I solve this problem.

```py
if event.message.text[0:6] == 'push**':
    t = event.message.text
    text = t.split('**')
    child = subprocess.Popen(['./notify.py'], shell=True, cwd='/app', stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print('test')
    return 0


/bin/sh: 1: ./notify.py: Permission denied
```

Comment: Why do you want to run these subprocesses using ``shell=True``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I thought it's necessary, so how should I do for solving this problem

Comment: I change the code like this
child = subprocess.Popen(['./notify.py'], cwd='/app', stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

then I get the error code below:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: './notify.py'

Comment: What permissions does ``notify.py`` have/is it created with?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I need to run notify.py in app.py, so I think the permissions: read.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem